# Kubuntu 14.10 multiple monitor issue: how to persist configuration?

Tags: ati, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, 14.10, kde

I have a problem with configuring multiple monitors in Kubuntu 14.10.

The system is an AMD A8-3850 (Llano). The driver manager shows this as `Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6550D]` with both, HDMI and DVI in use with a Full-HD monitor on each.

The driver manager gives me three options:

- Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx
- Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates
- Using X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display drier wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (Recommended Driver)

The driver is `fglrx-updates`. I do not use `xserver-xorg-video-ati` because that somehow doesn't allow me to configure multiple monitors at all. Even worse, it only displays 1440x1050 resolution on my Full HD screens.

The monitors are recognized as DFP1 and DFP2. I managed, using `amdcccle`, to get X in general know about my multiple monitors. So, when the login screen appears, it has both monitors active, and the login window appears on the screen on which the mouse pointer is. In KDE system settings I configure:

```
DFP1
    Size: 1920x1080 (Auto)
    Refresh: Auto
    Orientation: No Rotation
    Position: Absolute 1940 0

DFP2
    Size: 1920x1080 (Auto)
    Refresh: Auto
    Orientation: No Rotation
    Position: Absolute 0 0

Primary output: DFP2
```

Physically, DFP2 is left of DFP1. The position 1940 instead of 1920 is intentional. I do not want to disable the glowing borders, but I do not want that the glowing border of a window on one screen is "shining" into the other screen when I'm recording screencasts.

The problem is: KDE "forgets" these settings. Once I logout and login again, the settings are gone. Even worse, KDE then effectively configures everything to clone: DFP1 and DFP2 both have position `0,0`, although DFP1 should have position `1940,0`.

I've tried both, just "Apply" button and "Save as Default".

How can I make my desktop screen / monitor configuration persistent?

P.S.:
I suspect that the package that is responsible for this misbehavior is `kscreen`.